# Пропорциональное вписывание изображения

Tags: html, css

Нужно вписать изображение в `div` фиксированного размера, но так, чтобы **больший** размер изображения занимал 100% div'а, а меньший - сколько получится. Если подгонять только один фиксированный размер, то это выглядит так

```
  div {
    width: 125px;
    height: 70px; 
  }
  div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Но если у изображения высота больше, чем ширина, то получается швах. Решается ли проблема на CSS?

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову - всё таки `js`, не уверен что этот вопрос можно решить с помощью `css`, хотя ответ показывает как можно сделать небольшой "костыль": кладите в родительский блок другой `div` и вставляйте нужную картинку фоном.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно свойство `background-size`.
Например:

```
div {
    background: url(/example/image/mybg.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**cover**

Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.

**contain**

Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.

Источник: https://webref.ru/css/background-size

---

А если именно с тегом img нужно, то может такое решение устроит?

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 125px;
}

.ex2 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 70px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/70/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/70/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/70/100/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/70/100/" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Я так думаю, что нужно работать с тегом `img` и вы неправильно поняли вопрос.

Comment: Добавил к ответу еще решение. Что думаете?

Comment: Неплохое решение, думаю должно подойти

Comment: Спасибо. Остановился на диве с бэкграундом. Только с той поправкой, что `position` указал 50%, а не 100

Answer (score 3):

Можно еще проще, с `object-fit: contain`. Тогда изображение автоматически центрируется. Замена на `object-fit: cover` растянет картинку на весь блок, тоже с автоматическим центрированием.

```
div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:contain;
}
```

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 125px;
}

.ex2 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 70px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

div.cover img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/140/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/140/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/300/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/300/" alt=""></div>
<br>
<div class="ex1 cover"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/140/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2 cover"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/140/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex1 cover"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/300/" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2 cover"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/300/" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Да если бы у него была поддержка IE/Edge https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit, то было бы идеально.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с ответом [Romchik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699561/220571), но без абсолютного позиционирования (расположение за счёт flexbox):

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 125px;
}

.ex2 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 70px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  
  /* сделать inline flex-контейнером */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* центрировать элементы горизонтально */
  justify-content: center;
  /* центрировать элементы вертикально */
  align-items: center;
}

div img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w5wV.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w5wV.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex1"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkg7V.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="ex2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkg7V.jpg" alt=""></div>
```